# Creating keyboard shortcut for converting a file (photo or document) to pdf

Tags: pdf

I'd like to set up a simple keyboard shortcut that would save the currently selected file in the finder as a pdf, assuming it is a filetype that can be converted to pdf. I've already followed this [nice shortcut for doing this when the document is open](http://macsparky.com/blog/2008/3/19/keyboard-shortcut-for-save-as-pdf-in-os-x.html), but now I'm looking to take this one step further and have it work on the file from the finder.

Comment: Box of chocolates ?  I mean what is the original file format or are they different.

Comment: What about creating a Automator service ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution with Automator if you are just handling images

You can batch convert these files by:

1. Open **Automator** from `/Applications`
2. Create a new **Service**
3. Drag the **Get Specified Finder Items** to the workflow builder.
4. Drag the **New Pdf From Image** to the workflow builder
5. Save the service & bind it your keyboard shortcut preferences

If you're using other filetypes, you may you the **Print finder items** action. But it will use a popup if I'm not mistaken.